# SQL - Like and wildcard, not expected result

Tags: sql, wildcard, sql-like

I'm still a newbie with SQL so please be patient with me.

I have got the following WHERE statement in a query:

```
WHERE Scopes.Name = 'APAC' AND Sites.City LIKE '%o%'
```

It's producing the following result (as expected):
[image: click here to see the picture]

While if I remove the ending wildcard, like this:

```
WHERE Scopes.Name = 'APAC' AND Sites.City LIKE '%o'
```

It results in an empty table.
What I cannot understand is that the city name "Repetto" clearly ends with a "o", thus LIKE '%o' in the query should be producing the same result as LIKE '%o%'.

Am I misunderstanding the use of the wildcards?
Can anyone kindly explain to me the logic behind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of wildcards is correct.  What this means is that there is a character after the `o` in `'Repetto'`.

This could be a hidden character or a space.  One possibility is that the column is declared as a `char()` rather than a `varchar()`, so the value is padded with spaces.

Comment: Well it's indeed char(255). But where this thing of the padding comes from? I mean, what's with this need to add spaces that shouldn't be there?

Comment: Found the explanation on Google, thanks Gordon for the tip!
The short answer is: VARCHAR is variable length, while CHAR is fixed length. CHAR is a fixed length string data type, so any remaining space in the field is padded with blanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that "Repetto " has an ending "space" character.

```
WHERE Scopes.Name = 'APAC' AND TRIM(Sites.City) LIKE '%o'
```

If this is the case, "Repetto" with the ending space does not match the '%o' wildcard expression but '%o%' does.

Comment: No spaces, at least not manually added spaces. I have double checked.